# Using Angular matcher for route throws "Consider changing the function expression into an exported function"

Tags: angular, routes, matcher

I wonder if you guys can help with this code! because I think I'm going out of my mind

This is the `\helpers\matcher.ts(4,12)`:

```
import { UrlMatcher , UrlSegment } from "@angular/router";

export function match(path: string): UrlMatcher {
    return function matcher(url: UrlSegment[], group) {
        console.log(path, url, group);
        if (url.length > 0 && url[0].path === path) {
            return { consumed: [url[0]] };
        }
        return null;
    };
}
```

This is the error I get when I do ng build --prod

> ERROR in src\app\app.module.ts(124,30): Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
>
> Function expressions are not supported in decorators in 'rootRouterConfig'
>   'rootRouterConfig' references 'match'
>   'match' contains the error at src\app\shared\helpers\matcher.ts(4,12)
>   Consider changing the function expression into an exported function

But it compiles and works perfect with ng build and ng serve.

Here is the app.routes path

```
export const rootRouterConfig: Routes = [

    { path: ':param', component: HomeComponent,
        children: [
            { matcher: match('job-spec/:id'), component: JobSpecDetailsComponent },
            { path: '**',  redirectTo: '404' },
        ]
    },
];
```

And here is the app.module

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ....
        RouterModule.forRoot(rootRouterConfig, {
            useHash: false,
            scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
            anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
        }),
        ....
```

Comment: How do you define `rootRouterConfig`?

Comment: Hi @MaihanNijat I have updated my question

Comment: Try: `{ matcher: match, component: JobSpecDetailsComponent },` and `export function match(url: UrlSegment[]){}`.

Comment: @MaihanNijat -  it's complaining... about the type for  'matcher' /**
 * See `Routes` for more details.
 *
 * @publicApi
 */
export interface Route {
    path?: string;
    pathMatch?: string;
    matcher?: UrlMatcher;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot test it but try the following:

```
export function match(url: UrlSegment[]): UrlMatcher {
    if (url.length > 0 && url[0].path === path) {
       return { consumed: [url[0]] };
    }
    return null;
}
```

And use it as:

```
{ matcher: match, component: JobSpecDetailsComponent },
```

The `URL` has the path, but not sure your need why you want to pass the path again. Use the path statically and see if it compiles, and then figure it out your path.